# composer requireでエラーが出る: Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: laravel

**やりたいこと**
laravel-notification-channels/twitterをインストールしたい
https://github.com/laravel-notification-channels/twitter

**やったこと**
docker-composeコマンドを使ってインストールしてます

```
$ docker-compose exec workspace composer require laravel-notification-channels/twitter
```

**エラー**

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel-notification-channels/twitter v5.0.1
    - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - Installation request for laravel-notification-channels/twitter ^5.0 -> satisfiable by laravel-notification-channels/twitter[v5.0.0, v5.0.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - laravel-notification-channels/twitter v5.0.0 requires illuminate/notifications ^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/notifications[8.x-dev, v8.0.0, v8.0.1, v8.0.2, v8.0.3, v8.0.4, v8.1.0, v8.2.0, v8.3.0, v8.4.0, v8.5.0, v8.6.0, v8.7.0, v8.7.1, v8.8.0, v8.9.0].
    - don't install illuminate/notifications 8.x-dev|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.0.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.0.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.0.2|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.0.3|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.0.4|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.1.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.2.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.3.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.5.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.6.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.7.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.7.1|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.8.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - don't install illuminate/notifications v8.9.0|don't install laravel/framework v6.18.42
    - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v6.18.42, required as ^6.2) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v6.18.42].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

**composer update**コマンドを試しましたが、結果は変わりませんでした。

**追記**
Dockerの環境はLaradockを用いて以下のGitHubからクローンして使用しています。
https://github.com/Laradock/laradock.git -b v9.6

Dockerfile.json

```
{
    "aliases": [
        "docker"
    ],
    "case_insensitive": true,
    "keywords": "from maintainer expose env arg user onbuild stopsignal",
    "contains": [
        {
            "className": "comment",
            "begin": "#",
            "end": "$",
            "contains": [
                {
                    "begin": "\\b(a|an|the|are|I'm|isn't|don't|doesn't|won't|but|just|should|pretty|simply|enough|gonna|going|wtf|so|such|will|you|your|they|like|more)\\b"
                },
                {
                    "className": "doctag",
                    "begin": "(?:TODO|FIXME|NOTE|BUG|XXX):",
                    "relevance": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "className": "string",
            "begin": "'",
            "end": "'",
            "illegal": "\\n",
            "contains": [
                {
                    "begin": "\\\\[\\s\\S]",
                    "relevance": 0
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "className": "string",
            "begin": "\"",
            "end": "\"",
            "illegal": "\\n",
            "contains": [
                {
                    "$ref": "#contains.1.contains.0"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "className": "number",
            "begin": "\\b\\d+(\\.\\d+)?",
            "relevance": 0
        },
        {
            "beginKeywords": "run cmd entrypoint volume add copy workdir label healthcheck shell",
            "starts": {
                "end": "[^\\\\]$",
                "subLanguage": "bash"
            }
        }
    ],
    "illegal": "<\/"
}
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "laravel/framework": "^6.2",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.4",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "facade/ignition": "^1.4",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8.0"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ]
    }
}
```

**Workspaceコンテナ**

```
version: '3'

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}
  backend:
    driver: ${NETWORKS_DRIVER}

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: ${VOLUMES_DRIVER}
　～略

services:

### Workspace Utilities ##################################
    workspace:
      build:
        context: ./workspace
        args:
          - CHANGE_SOURCE=${CHANGE_SOURCE}
          - UBUNTU_SOURCE=${UBUNTU_SOURCE}
          - LARADOCK_PHP_VERSION=${PHP_VERSION}
          - LARADOCK_PHALCON_VERSION=${PHALCON_VERSION}
          - INSTALL_SUBVERSION=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SUBVERSION}
          - INSTALL_XDEBUG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XDEBUG}
          - INSTALL_PCOV=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PCOV}
          - INSTALL_PHPDBG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPDBG}
          - INSTALL_BLACKFIRE=${INSTALL_BLACKFIRE}
          - INSTALL_SSH2=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSH2}
          - INSTALL_GMP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GMP}
          - INSTALL_SOAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SOAP}
          - INSTALL_XSL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_XSL}
          - INSTALL_LDAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LDAP}
          - INSTALL_SMB=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SMB}
          - INSTALL_IMAP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAP}
          - INSTALL_MONGO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MONGO}
          - INSTALL_AMQP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AMQP}
          - INSTALL_CASSANDRA=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_CASSANDRA}
          - INSTALL_GEARMAN=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GEARMAN}
          - INSTALL_PHPREDIS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHPREDIS}
          - INSTALL_MSSQL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MSSQL}
          - NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR=${WORKSPACE_NVM_NODEJS_ORG_MIRROR}
          - INSTALL_NODE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NODE}
          - NPM_REGISTRY=${WORKSPACE_NPM_REGISTRY}
          - INSTALL_YARN=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_YARN}
          - INSTALL_NPM_GULP=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_GULP}
          - INSTALL_NPM_BOWER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_BOWER}
          - INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_VUE_CLI}
          - INSTALL_NPM_ANGULAR_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_NPM_ANGULAR_CLI}
          - INSTALL_DRUSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUSH}
          - INSTALL_WP_CLI=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WP_CLI}
          - INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DRUPAL_CONSOLE}
          - INSTALL_AEROSPIKE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AEROSPIKE}
          - INSTALL_OCI8=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_OCI8}
          - INSTALL_V8JS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_V8JS}
          - COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_GLOBAL_INSTALL}
          - COMPOSER_AUTH=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_AUTH}
          - COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST=${WORKSPACE_COMPOSER_REPO_PACKAGIST}
          - INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_WORKSPACE_SSH}
          - INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_ENVOY}
          - INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LARAVEL_INSTALLER}
          - INSTALL_DEPLOYER=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DEPLOYER}
          - INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PRESTISSIMO}
          - INSTALL_LINUXBREW=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LINUXBREW}
          - INSTALL_MC=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MC}
          - INSTALL_SYMFONY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SYMFONY}
          - INSTALL_PYTHON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PYTHON}
          - INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGE_OPTIMIZERS}
          - INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IMAGEMAGICK}
          - INSTALL_TERRAFORM=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TERRAFORM}
          - INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_DUSK_DEPS}
          - INSTALL_PG_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PG_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_PHALCON=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PHALCON}
          - INSTALL_SWOOLE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SWOOLE}
          - INSTALL_TAINT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_TAINT}
          - INSTALL_LIBPNG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_LIBPNG}
          - INSTALL_IONCUBE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_IONCUBE}
          - INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MYSQL_CLIENT}
          - INSTALL_PING=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_PING}
          - INSTALL_SSHPASS=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SSHPASS}
          - INSTALL_INOTIFY=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_INOTIFY}
          - INSTALL_FSWATCH=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_FSWATCH}
          - INSTALL_AST=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_AST}
          - INSTALL_YAML=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_YAML}
          - INSTALL_MAILPARSE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_MAILPARSE}
          - PUID=${WORKSPACE_PUID}
          - PGID=${WORKSPACE_PGID}
          - CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_CHROME_DRIVER_VERSION}
          - NODE_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_NODE_VERSION}
          - YARN_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_YARN_VERSION}
          - DRUSH_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_DRUSH_VERSION}
          - AST_VERSION=${WORKSPACE_AST_VERSION}
          - TZ=${WORKSPACE_TIMEZONE}
          - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_ID}
          - BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN=${BLACKFIRE_CLIENT_TOKEN}
          - INSTALL_POWERLINE=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_POWERLINE}
          - INSTALL_SUPERVISOR=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_SUPERVISOR}
          - INSTALL_FFMPEG=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_FFMPEG}
          - INSTALL_GNU_PARALLEL=${WORKSPACE_INSTALL_GNU_PARALLEL}
          - http_proxy
          - https_proxy
          - no_proxy
      volumes:
        - ${APP_CODE_PATH_HOST}:${APP_CODE_PATH_CONTAINER}${APP_CODE_CONTAINER_FLAG}
        - ./php-worker/supervisord.d:/etc/supervisord.d
      extra_hosts:
        - "dockerhost:${DOCKER_HOST_IP}"
      ports:
        - "${WORKSPACE_SSH_PORT}:22"
      tty: true
      environment:
        - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=${PHP_IDE_CONFIG}
        - DOCKER_HOST=tcp://docker-in-docker:2375
      networks:
        - frontend
        - backend
      links:
        - docker-in-docker
```

Comment: `docker-compose` コマンドはあくまで Docker 関連のコマンドなので、作業をしている Docker コンテナの情報も質問に含めておくと回答のヒントになるかもしれません。

Comment: dockerの情報とcomposer.jsonを追記しました。